# Einen Satz mit «dass» anfangen

Tags: meaning

Das ist etwas, dem ich oft begegne, aber nie ganz verstehe. Was bedeutet es, wenn man einen Satz mit «dass» anfängt? Ich lese jetzt einen [Artikel](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/wirtschaft/streit-um-made-in-germany-label-ohne-wert-1.1743839), der um den Streit um das `Made in Germany` Label geht und ich bin diesem Satz begegnet :

> Dass die EU nun genau regeln will, welche Kriterien für Herkunftsbezeichnungen ausschlaggebend sind, passt führenden Industrievertretern überhaupt nicht.

Ich glaube, dass es hier «since» bedeutet, aber ich weiß nicht ganz genau.

Comment: In most cases, it might help to replace *dass* with *the fact/idea/belief/… that* (die Tatsache/…, dass), where *the fact* is part of the main clause. So in your example: “Die Tatsache, dass die EU …, passt führenden Industrievertretern überhaupt nicht.“ Or in English: “The fact, that the EU wants to regulate …, is not congenial at all to leading industrial representatives.” (Translating as directly as possible, thus producing horrible English.) As in this example, I would almost never say that this construction is a good translation, but it might help to understand the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, you can silently insert a *”the fact that …”* to make the sentence complete.

> [Die Tatsache,] dass er mit den Kindern im Garten spielen wollte …
>
> [Die Tatsache,] dass die EU nun genau regeln will, welche …

It's just an omission.

Comment: I strongly oppose the idea that it's "just an omission". How did you arrive at that idea? Such an explanation would be peculiar for the usual case of a subordinate clause, "Es ist klar, dass die EU nun ..."--that would be quite difficult in fact--and it's not needed either to explain the transposed sentence. That *the fact that it* works anyway may have something to do with the whole story, but it's not the whole story. Why would anyone start saying that, and then omit it? I mean it's a jarring construction to begin with, that I don't think were just. But it's just useful.

Comment: The omission I'm referring to is "die Tatsache" and not the totally different construct that you introduce ("Es ist klar"). Other than that, I'm not sure what you're objecting to or what you're even trying to say.

Comment: @teylin, I'm taking a shortcut, assuming for sake of the argument that "Es" is equivalent to "die Tatsache". You could equivalently transpose your own example in the same way, "Die Tatsache passt nicht, dass ...", which already sounds misconstrued. "Es" in its position only works because the referent is indefinite, i.e. more general, but it certainly includes "die Tatsache". We strictly do not say "Es, dass ..., ist klar". I'm implying that the process that you allege didn't happen that way and you would be hard pressed to show it did.

Comment: You're missing the point. Are you a native speaker of German? `Es ist klar` conveys an opinion, but it is not what is missing in a sentence that starts with `dass` as the samples above. If you simply omit `Es ist klar`, you can't build a sentence starting with `dass`. `Es ist klar dass die EU viele Mitglieder hat.`. You can't just leave out the `Es ist klar` and write `Dass die EU viele Mitglieder hat.` That sentence fragment does not make any sense. However, starting with `Die Tatsache, dass die EU viele Mitglieder hat ist allen hier bekannt.`, you CAN remove `Die Tatsache` and the remaining

Comment: sentence still makes sense `Dass die EU viele Mitglieder hat ist allen hier bekannt.`. Therefore, a sentence that starts with `dass` and still makes sense most likely has an omitted `die Tatsache`.

Comment: Die Tatsache, dass "die Tatsache" leichter einzufügen ist als "Es" is bemerkenswert, ändert aber nichts an meiner Aussage im Rahmen einer einfachen Syntaxanalyse, in der beide jeweils eine Nominalphrase darstellen. Dass "Es" nicht einfach eingefügt werden kann spricht gegen die hiesige Antwort ebenso wie die Beliebigkeit von ausgerechnet "die Tatsache", da wohl "Der Punkt" o.ä auch geht.

Comment: Sorry, aber du verstehst immer noch nicht was ich mit meiner Antwort sage.

Comment: Da gibt's nicht viel zu verstehen. Die Antwort enthält eine unbelegte Behauptung. Man könnte genauso behaupten, die Englische Variante sei nur eine redundante Reduplikation. Die wortwörtliche Übersetzung wäre im Englischen wohl nicht unüblich ([ref.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4119/the-fact-that-versus-just-that)). Mir scheint es so als ginge diese Antwort vom Gegenteil aus. Ich sehe also das Problem gar nicht. Die Frage ist so generell formuliert, dass die Antwort formal nicht dem Anspruch genügt.

Comment: OK, I'll add a few examples that will all work with "die tatsache" and without it. Can you add some examples where `es ist klar` can be omitted or inserted ad libitum? `dass rot und blau lila ergeben weiss doch jeder`, `dass die Sonne im Osten aufgeht gilt sogar für die Südhalbkugel.` So, can you produce a few sentences that start with `dass` where YOUR claim (which I still don't understand) works?

Comment: Should I first explain my claim again? I implied that a different derivation from a different syntax exists. I guess, still, that it's just a reversal of the more usual construction, where the conjunction joins two verbal phrases, where your claim would likewise have to be true, ie. *Ihnen passt die Tatsache überhaupt nicht, dass ...*. I might have been wrong that "Es ist ... dass ..." were the usual case, though I see no argument for or against that claim. It may be even more complicated. I find that "Es, dass" cannot lead the sentence, but "es" works in "Ihnen passt es ...". [cont.]

Comment: [cont] I can transpose "Es ist klar, dass ..." to "Dass ..., ist klar", omitting "Es". That is not "just an omission", if I can't insert it back. Maybe I don't as a matter of pragmatics, not grammar, if "Es" refers back to a specification and thus doesn't need to be followed by a specification, but I can also delete and transpose in the matrix sentence: "Klar ist, dass ...". So we have a circular argument, unless it can be grounded in a reasonable premises (the entry into the circle, so to speak). My premises was, that you can hardly insert "die T." into "Es ist klar, dass ...". [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] "Es ist Tatsache, dass ..." is frequent, though. After all, an explanation for "dass" was easier to find to support my point, although it's almost too simple and an explanation from a learners perspective would be important, too. The conjunction developed from the determiner, "das" as in all Germanic languages, [DWDS/dass](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dass). They give an arbitrary, perhaps insufficient ex., "Ich weiß das, er kommt". In this, "das" is Object. Yet, "die Tatsache" is Subject. Proto-Indo-European as well as the majority of the world's languages are SOV, so you may have a point.

Comment: I'm zoning out. I don't know what your problem is and I don't understand what you are driving at. Unsubscribing.

Comment: PS: Equivalently one could take for example "[Es ist klar], das[s] Schreiben ermüdet". Although up to now I was neither suggesting that omission, nor the analogy to the determiner. It's notable that SOV does still exists in some poetry (sorry, I have no examples at hand, I might even be wrong). We could as well insert what was suggested suggest "Es ist klar die Tatsache" (ie. it is clearly the case), but that wouldn't be idiomatic.

Comment: You're still not getting it.

Comment: I did say that native speaker intuition may differ, and that it's important too, but if I don't share that intuition, I *can't get it*. That's the whole point of my comment. You are basically saying that speakers hear--for lack of a better word--hear an initial noun, even if it isn't there, but I don't. And I won't believe it, if you can't explain it.

Comment: I'm not saying the words that you claim I'm saying. Read my answer again. In scenarios where a sentence starting with `dass` is a complete and full statement, the missing bit to make it gramatically correct can be supplied by pre-pending the sentence with `die Tatsache`. That's really all there is to it. You, again, YOU, have chosen to introduce a totally unrelated spin that does not make sense with sentences that start with `dass`.

Comment: Just look at the comments of the last few days, and look at the upvotes for my comments. None of your comments have a vote, so nobody seems to be able to follow your point. Now, can you please just give it a rest

Comment: Statt ein "Die Tatsache" aus der Luft zu greifen liegt es doch viel näher, den Satz umzustellen und "Industrievertretern passt nicht, dass die EU..." zu sagen.

Answer (score 8):

It means:

> Führenden Industrievertretern passt überhaupt nicht, dass die EU nun genau regeln will, welche Kriterien für Herkunftsbezeichnungen ausschlaggebend sind.

In this case, you can invert the sentence for it has a complete meaning.

---

In other cases, however, it could be important what is before the *dass*. Say,

> Dass er mit den Kindern im Garten spielen wollte. Dass er hungrig war. Dass er den Kindern geholfen hat, die Hausaufgaben zu machen. (Ende)

If you see something like that, you might have overlooked an expression like the following one in parenthesis:

> (Sie freute sich darüber, dass er gekommen ist.) Dass er mit den Kindern im Garten spielen wollte. Dass er hungrig war. Dass er den Kindern geholfen hat, die Hausaufgaben zu machen. (Ende)

*Dass* inherits here rather the meaning of the preposition *über* in *darüber, dass...*

Comment: Das ist aber doch falsches Deutsch; statt Punkten müssten hier Kommas stehen. `Dass er hungrig war.` ist kein Satz.

Comment: @userunknown Ok, danke für den downvote. Was Sie sagen, stimmt aber nicht: *"Sie lachte gerne. Darüber, dass er aufstand und ihr den Stuhl zurechtrückte. Dass er den Champagnerkorken knallen ließ. Dass er mit ihr anstieß. Dass er sie so vorsichtig nach dem Leben als attraktive Frau in einem gottverlassenen Dorf in den Bergen fragte."* Aus B. Schlinks ,,Sommerlügen"

Comment: Und wer ist B. Schlinks? Der Leibhaftige, Unfehlbare, göttliche?

Comment: @userunknown Schlink ist ein Nutzer der deutschen Sprache -- wie Sie. Die Tatschache, dass er Romane schreibt, veröffentlicht und verkauft, lässt mich vermuten, dass seine Werke *wenigstens*  hohe grammatische Qualitätmaßnähme erfüllen.

Comment: Es ist aber schon ungewöhnlich. Literarische Texte sind das eine, aber in Gebrauchstexten wird man so etwas eher nicht finden.

Answer (score 5):

It might be easier to understand, if you move the part of the sentence with the word "dass" to the end of the sentence and translate it with "that" (Like in "I think, that you shouldn't do that"). We are talking about "Hauptsatz" and "Nebensatz" here. In German you can append those together in different orders. Sometimes you can also insert one of them into the other (The "Nebensatz" into the "Hauptsatz"). But back to the "dass". "dass" indicates (almost) always a "Nebensatz". This is a part of the sentence, that's (dont translate "that" with "dass" here) less important for the sentence, but may make up all the sense.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to parse it as "Das [descriptive phrase] passt führenden Industrievertretern überhaupt nicht" - with an article. Of course, the phrase is not trivial (it seems to be verbal phrase, I guess, but I don't think that matters here).

The prototypical example would surely not involve another article or pronoun. I suppose rather a *zu-infinitive* might explain the construction best to an English speaker: "Er glaubt, dass zu verhandeln eine schlechte Idee ist", which might as well be "Dass zu verhandeln eine gute Idee ist, [das] glaubt er nicht", where the [das] is optional, and the zu-infinitive not really needed and bad style, but passable and in accord with English, "He believes that to negotiate would be ...", where Modern English prefers a noun "negotiation" in that place, or even the gerund "negotiating", too.

; A construction *determiner/conjunction* + *to (zu)* + *infinitive* would also explain the construction of the English to-infinitive, as the determiner would have it look all the more like a noun, "that to-do is a thing I have to do soon". Although, I have to admit I have not faintest clue about the scholarly consensus on this matter of history. It doesn't really matter here, if the only aim is to understanding the phrase.